# scala issue with reading file from resources directory

Tags: scala, sbt

I wrote something like this to read file from resource directory:

```
val filePath = MyClass.getClass.getResource("/myFile.csv")
val file = filePath.getFile
println(file)
CSVReader.open(file)
```

and the result I got was something like this:

```
file:/path/to/project/my_module/src/main/resources/my_module-assembly-0.1.jar!/myFile.csv

Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/path/to/project/my_module/src/main/resources/my_module-assembly-0.1.jar!/myFile.csv (No such file or directory)
```

Whereas, if I run the same code in IDE(Intellij), no issues and the path printed to console is:

```
/path/to/project/my_module/target/scala-2.11/classes/myFile.csv
```

FYI, its a multi build project with a couple of modules and I build the jars using `sbt assembly`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is more related to Java or the JVM itself than to Scala or SBT.

There is a difference when running your application from the IDE vs the command line (or outside the IDE). The method `getClass.getResource(...)` attempts to find the resource URL in the **current** classpath, and that's the key difference.

If you look at the URL itself, you will find that in the first case you have a `my_module-assembly-0.1.jar!` bit in it, meaning that URL is actually pointing towards the contents of the JAR, not to a file accessible from the file system.

From inside your IDE your class path will include the actual files on disk, from the source folders, because the IDE assumes that there is not any JAR file itself. So when obtaining the URL given by `getClass.getResource(...)` you have an URL that does not have the `my_module-assembly-0.1.jar!` bit in it.

---

Since you want to read the contents of the file, you may want to do a `getClass.getResourceAsStream(...)`. That will give you an `InputStream` that you can use to read the contents regardless you are in the IDE or anywhere else.

Your `CSVReader` class may have a method that allows it read the data from an `InputStream` or a `Reader` or something similar.

**EDIT:** As pointed out by Luis [Miguel Mejia Suarez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4111404/luis-miguel-mej%C3%ADa-su%C3%A1rez), a more Scala idiomatic way of reading files from your class path is using the [`Source.fromResource` method](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/io/Source%24.html#fromResource(resource:String,classLoader:ClassLoader)(implicitcodec:scala.io.Codec):scala.io.BufferedSource). This will return a `BufferedSource` that then can be used to read the file contents.

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez Great answer! However one note, in Scala we have the [`fromResource` _method_](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/io/Source$.html#fromResource(resource:String,classLoader:ClassLoader)(implicitcodec:scala.io.Codec):scala.io.BufferedSource) on the **Source** class to read the contents of a resource - IMHO, you may update the answer to use it instead of `getClass.getResourceAsStream` which is more Java.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez good point, I'll add it as a side note since we don't know how the `CSVReader` API looks like and may not be able to read data from a Scala `BufferedSource`.